# Twitter Bootstrap Row Nesting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm still new with Twitter Bootstrap and the whole grid framework, so please bear with me if this seems like a very noobish question.

But here is what I have so far [in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr3Q6/18/).

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="install_files2/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="install_files/docs/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" /> -->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid" style="background-color:;">
            <div class="span2" style="background-color:red;"></div>
            <div class="span2" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
            <div class="span2" style="background-color:red;"></div>
            <div class="span2" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
            <div class="span2" style="background-color:red;"></div>
            <div class="span1" style="background-color:blue;min-height:100px;">
            </div>
            <div class="span1" style="background-color:red;min-height:100px;">
            </div>
            <div class="span2" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v2.1.1
 *
 * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world @twitter by @mdo and @fat.
 */

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.hide-text {
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
.input-block-level {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}
audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
}
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0;
}
sub,
sup {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}
img {
  /* Responsive images (ensure images don't scale beyond their parents) */

  max-width: 100%;
  /* Part 1: Set a maxium relative to the parent */

  width: auto\9;
  /* IE7-8 need help adjusting responsive images */

  height: auto;
  /* Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, */
  /*         otherwise you get stretching */

  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
#map_canvas img {
  max-width: none;
}
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
button,
input {
  *overflow: visible;
  line-height: normal;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
a {
  color: #0088cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #005580;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.img-rounded {
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.img-polaroid {
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.img-circle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
  -moz-border-radius: 500px;
  border-radius: 500px;
}
.row {
  margin-left: -20px;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.row:after {
  clear: both;
}
[class*="span"] {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  /*margin-left: 20px;*/
}
.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: 940px;
}
.span12 {
  width: 940px;
}
.span11 {
  width: 860px;
}
.span10 {
  width: 780px;
}
.span9 {
  width: 700px;
}
.span8 {
  width: 620px;
}
.span7 {
  width: 540px;
}
.span6 {
  width: 460px;
}
.span5 {
  width: 380px;
}
.span4 {
  width: 300px;
}
.span3 {
  width: 220px;
}
.span2 {
  width: 140px;
}
.span1 {
  width: 60px;
}
.offset12 {
  margin-left: 980px;
}
.offset11 {
  margin-left: 900px;
}
.offset10 {
  margin-left: 820px;
}
.offset9 {
  margin-left: 740px;
}
.offset8 {
  margin-left: 660px;
}
.offset7 {
  margin-left: 580px;
}
.offset6 {
  margin-left: 500px;
}
.offset5 {
  margin-left: 420px;
}
.offset4 {
  margin-left: 340px;
}
.offset3 {
  margin-left: 260px;
}
.offset2 {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
.offset1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.row-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.row-fluid:before,
.row-fluid:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.row-fluid:after {
  clear: both;
}
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 220px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  /*margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;*/
  /**margin-left: 2.074468085106383%;*/
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .row {
    margin-left: -30px;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  .row:before,
  .row:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
  }
  .row:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  [class*="span"] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    /*margin-left: 30px;*/
  }
  .container,
  .navbar-static-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
  .span12 {
    width: 1170px;
  }
  .span11 {
    width: 1070px;
  }
  .span10 {
    width: 970px;
  }
  .span9 {
    width: 870px;
  }
  .span8 {
    width: 770px;
  }
  .span7 {
    width: 670px;
  }
  .span6 {
    width: 570px;
  }
  .span5 {
    width: 470px;
  }
  .span4 {
    width: 370px;
  }
  .span3 {
    width: 270px;
  }
  .span2 {
    width: 170px;
  }
  .span1 {
    width: 70px;
  }
  .offset12 {
    margin-left: 1230px;
  }
  .offset11 {
    margin-left: 1130px;
  }
  .offset10 {
    margin-left: 1030px;
  }
  .offset9 {
    margin-left: 930px;
  }
  .offset8 {
    margin-left: 830px;
  }
  .offset7 {
    margin-left: 730px;
  }
  .offset6 {
    margin-left: 630px;
  }
  .offset5 {
    margin-left: 530px;
  }
  .offset4 {
    margin-left: 430px;
  }
  .offset3 {
    margin-left: 330px;
  }
  .offset2 {
    margin-left: 230px;
  }
  .offset1 {
    margin-left: 130px;
  }
  .row-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  .row-fluid:before,
  .row-fluid:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
  }
  .row-fluid:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    /*margin-left: 2.564102564102564%;*/
    /**margin-left: 2.5109110747408616%;*/
  }
  .row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .row-fluid .span12 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 99.94680851063829%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span11 {
    width: 91.45299145299145%;
    *width: 91.39979996362975%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span10 {
    width: 82.90598290598291%;
    *width: 82.8527914166212%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span9 {
    width: 74.35897435897436%;
    *width: 74.30578286961266%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span8 {
    width: 65.81196581196582%;
    *width: 65.75877432260411%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span7 {
    width: 57.26495726495726%;
    *width: 57.21176577559556%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span6 {
    width: 48.717948717948715%;
    *width: 48.664757228587014%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span5 {
    width: 71.42857142857145%;
    *width: 71.42857142857145%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span4 {
    width: 31.623931623931625%;
    *width: 31.570740134569924%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span3 {
    width: 23.076923076923077%;
    *width: 23.023731587561375%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span2 {
    width: 14.28571428571429%;
    *width: 14.28571428571429%;
  }
  .row-fluid .span1 {
    width: 7.142857142857143%;
    *width: 7.142857142857143%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset12 {
    margin-left: 105.12820512820512%;
    *margin-left: 105.02182214948171%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset12:first-child {
    margin-left: 102.56410256410257%;
    *margin-left: 102.45771958537915%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset11 {
    margin-left: 96.58119658119658%;
    *margin-left: 96.47481360247316%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset11:first-child {
    margin-left: 94.01709401709402%;
    *margin-left: 93.91071103837061%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset10 {
    margin-left: 88.03418803418803%;
    *margin-left: 87.92780505546462%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset10:first-child {
    margin-left: 85.47008547008548%;
    *margin-left: 85.36370249136206%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset9 {
    margin-left: 79.48717948717949%;
    *margin-left: 79.38079650845607%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset9:first-child {
    margin-left: 76.92307692307693%;
    *margin-left: 76.81669394435352%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset8 {
    margin-left: 70.94017094017094%;
    *margin-left: 70.83378796144753%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset8:first-child {
    margin-left: 68.37606837606839%;
    *margin-left: 68.26968539734497%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset7 {
    margin-left: 62.393162393162385%;
    *margin-left: 62.28677941443899%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset7:first-child {
    margin-left: 59.82905982905982%;
    *margin-left: 59.72267685033642%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset6 {
    margin-left: 53.84615384615384%;
    *margin-left: 53.739770867430444%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset6:first-child {
    margin-left: 51.28205128205128%;
    *margin-left: 51.175668303327875%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset5 {
    margin-left: 45.299145299145295%;
    *margin-left: 45.1927623204219%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset5:first-child {
    margin-left: 42.73504273504273%;
    *margin-left: 42.62865975631933%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset4 {
    margin-left: 36.75213675213675%;
    *margin-left: 36.645753773413354%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset4:first-child {
    margin-left: 34.18803418803419%;
    *margin-left: 34.081651209310785%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset3 {
    margin-left: 28.205128205128204%;
    *margin-left: 28.0987452264048%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset3:first-child {
    margin-left: 25.641025641025642%;
    *margin-left: 25.53464266230224%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset2 {
    margin-left: 19.65811965811966%;
    *margin-left: 19.551736679396257%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset2:first-child {
    margin-left: 17.094017094017094%;
    *margin-left: 16.98763411529369%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset1 {
    margin-left: 11.11111111111111%;
    *margin-left: 11.004728132387708%;
  }
  .row-fluid .offset1:first-child {
    margin-left: 8.547008547008547%;
    *margin-left: 8.440625568285142%;
  }
  input,
  textarea,
  .uneditable-input {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .controls-row [class*="span"] + [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  input.span12, textarea.span12, .uneditable-input.span12 {
    width: 1156px;
  }
  input.span11, textarea.span11, .uneditable-input.span11 {
    width: 1056px;
  }
  input.span10, textarea.span10, .uneditable-input.span10 {
    width: 956px;
  }
  input.span9, textarea.span9, .uneditable-input.span9 {
    width: 856px;
  }
  input.span8, textarea.span8, .uneditable-input.span8 {
    width: 756px;
  }
  input.span7, textarea.span7, .uneditable-input.span7 {
    width: 656px;
  }
  input.span6, textarea.span6, .uneditable-input.span6 {
    width: 556px;
  }
  input.span5, textarea.span5, .uneditable-input.span5 {
    width: 456px;
  }
  input.span4, textarea.span4, .uneditable-input.span4 {
    width: 356px;
  }
  input.span3, textarea.span3, .uneditable-input.span3 {
    width: 256px;
  }
  input.span2, textarea.span2, .uneditable-input.span2 {
    width: 156px;
  }
  input.span1, textarea.span1, .uneditable-input.span1 {
    width: 56px;
  }
  .thumbnails {
    margin-left: -30px;
  }
  .thumbnails > li {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .row-fluid .thumbnails {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to place 2 small boxes after that last big red box in the white space. I've done some research and I read that it required nesting a row inside a row and then placing a column. But that seemed to apply to a non-fluid application of the spans, i.e fixed widths. I am however measuring those boxes in percentages and am quite unsure as to how to proceed with nesting those rows. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this. One is to nest them as such:
(http://jsfiddle.net/rdTfe/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
       Red area here.
       <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">
            Small box
          </div>
          <div class="span6">
            Small box
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, this will extend the red container itself. So unless I misunderstand what you want to do, you don't really need to nest them.
(http://jsfiddle.net/rdTfe/1/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
       Red area here.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
      Small box
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      Small box
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nesting them this way makes sure the left and right edges of all your red box and other smaller boxes line up vertically.

**Update for Bootstrap 3**

The above examples can be written as such: http://jsfiddle.net/9wQ2M/10/

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       Red area here.
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Small box
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Small box
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And without nesting... http://jsfiddle.net/55z7p/3/

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       Red area here.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Small box
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Small box
    </div>
  </div>
```